# WiX Bundle: Determine point in time to start registry search

Tags: wix

I want to run two msi setups and afterwards install some files to the their locations. As the files I want to install are the same and big in size, I don't want to add these files to the msi's.

So I have a WiX bootstrapper bundle that installs the msi packages. These msi package write registry entries about their install location. Then, I want to read the install locations within the bootstrapper and copy the files to these locations.

My problem is, that the `util:RegistrySearch` is performed at the beginning. So it fails due to the non-existing registry entries.

Can I somehow determine the point in time to run the registry search? Or is there any other possibility to install the files from my WiX msi script without adding them two times to my bootstrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately impossible.